# Why is it that I can't personalize my own wallpaper in windows 7 starter?

Tags: windows, netbook

I'd be delighted to read technical reasons for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFIK, there is not technical reason for this, but rather is a marketing ploy by microsoft.  Windows 7 is targeted at low end, low margin machines, and MS saw fit to give a s very stripped down OS - with the option to upgrade to [Windows 7 home premium](http://store.microsoft.com/microsoft/Windows-Anytime-Upgrade-Windows-7-Starter-to-Home-Premium/product/83D7A62A) for an additional $80.

It's merely marketing - and while annoying, is probably a rather bright move on MS's part.

Answer (score 2):

There is no technical reason. It's just another limitation of the most basic edition.

Comment: What is and SKU?

Comment: [Stock-keeping unit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stock-keeping_unit): A stock-keeping unit or SKU (pronounced either as an acronym, /ˈskjuː/, or as an initialism, /ˌɛsˌkeɪˈjuː/) is a number or code used to identify different things for sale in a store or other business.

Comment: Well at least they permit to choose a black background. Which is what I used on my old desktop PC :P. Thanks Joey.